# Get single record from database Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am new to Django and trying to make a basic website and having a few difficulties getting the relevant record for a page.

Models.py

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from markdown import markdown

class LiveEntryManager(models.Manager):
      def get_query_set(self):
      return super(LiveEntryManager,self).get_query_set().filter(status=self.model.LIVE_STATUS)


class Page(models.Model):
      LIVE_STATUS = 1
      HIDDEN_STATUS = 2
      STATUS_CHOICES = (
            (LIVE_STATUS, 'Live'),
            (HIDDEN_STATUS, 'Hidden'),
       )
      title = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text='Max 250 characters.')
      slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, help_text='Suggested automatically generated from the title. Must be unique') 
      description = RichTextField()
      description_html = models.TextField(editable=False, blank=True) 
      status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=LIVE_STATUS, 
                           help_text="Only pages with live status will be publicly displayed")

      def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
          self.description_html = markdown(self.description)
          super(Page, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

      def get_record(self):
          return self.objects.get()

      #Managers
      live = LiveEntryManager()
      objects = models.Manager()

      class Meta:
            ordering = ['title']
            verbose_name_plural = "Pages"

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.title

      def get_absolute_url(self):
          return "/%s/" % self.slug

class Image(models.Model):
      page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery')

      class Meta:
            ordering = ['name']

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name
```

And Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list
from mainsite.models import Page, Image


def home(request):
    return render_to_response('templates/home.html')


def page(request, slug):
    one_page = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('templates/page/page.html',
                          { 'object_list': one_page.get_record() })
```

and Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   # Examples:
   url(r'^$', 'mainsite.views.home', name='home'),
   # url(r'^disability/', include('disability.foo.urls')),
   url(r'^page/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'mainsite.views.page'),
   # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
   # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
   url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
   # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

)

What I want to do is to be able to go to say /page/test and get the title, description and image for that object only. I know how to get all objects and display them in a template but cannot figure out how to get a single record and would be grateful of some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where'd you get `get_record()` from? The return value of `get_object_or_404` is a model instance. There's nothing else to "get", just pass the instance to your context. And, don't use `object_list` as a context name. Not only is this an instance, *not* a list or queryset, but that name is most often used with pagination, and you'll simply create confusion in your code if you're not actually paginating anything.

```
return render_to_response('templates/page/page.html', {
    'one_page': one_page,
})
```

Then in your template:

```
<h1>{{ one_page.title }}</h1>
<img src="{{ one_page.image.url }}" alt="">
<p>{{ one_page.description }}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks most of that worked for me, apart from the image, for some reason all I get is <img src="" /> when viewing the page.

Comment: Well, your model doesn't even have an `ImageField` on it. I just put it there for instructive purposes, but ultimately the data isn't just going to be pulled from the ether.

Comment: Alright so how would I get the related image field from the Image model?

Comment: You'd loop them with  `{% for image in one_page.image_set.all %}`. And, then `{{ image.image.url }}` for the image src.

Comment: It now shows the correct url in the img tag however I seems that it still cannot find the image and puts a placeholder to show broken image. I have looked at similar issues, could it be down to something missing in the request context?

Answer (score 2):

If you would want to query the database for a single Page model you could use

```
views.py

from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from models import Pages



def page(request, slug):
    try:
        page = Pages.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)
    return render(request, 'templates/page/page.html', {'page': page})
```

Then just use

```
{{page.title}}
```

or something like that in your template.

Also, if you want to query and have an iterable list returned intead you coule use

```
Pages.objects.filter()
```

instead of

```
Pages.objects.get()
```